# MySQL Case problem

Tags: mysql, case

I am trying to run a SQL code (I use MySQL). What I want to do is to set DATE_REACT a value when the first condition is satisfied, and a different value when the first condition is not satisfied. The problem is that the first condition is executed always, even when it shouldn't. What I am doing wrong?

```
UPDATE BILLS
SET STATE = 2,
DATE_REACT =
CASE 
WHEN (DATE_EM <= CURTIME() <= ADDTIME(DATE_EM, '00:02:00')) THEN ADDTIME(CURTIME(), '00:13:00')
ELSE ADDTIME(DATE_REACT, '00:13:00')
END
WHERE STATE = 1;
```

Comment: What is the datatype of `date_em`? Is it `TIME`, `DATE`, `DATETIME` or `TIMSETAMP`?

Comment: The datatype is TIME

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: OK then. Because the naming worried me that you might be comparing dates to times.

Answer (score 4):

You can't combine boolean expressions like that. Try it this way:

```
UPDATE BILLS
SET STATE = 2,
DATE_REACT =
CASE 
WHEN (DATE_EM <= CURTIME() AND CURTIME() <= ADDTIME(DATE_EM, '00:02:00')) THEN ADDTIME(CURTIME(), '00:13:00')
ELSE ADDTIME(DATE_REACT, '00:13:00')
END
WHERE STATE = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this part:

```
( DATE_EM <= CURTIME() <= ADDTIME(DATE_EM, '00:02:00') )
```

This is not allowed in SQL. The syntax `(a <= b <= c)` is valid in some languages, like Python but not in SQL. MySQL allows it but as you have found out, does something different and not what you want.

Replace it with `(a <= b AND b <= c)`:

```
( DATE_EM <= CURTIME() AND CURTIME() <= ADDTIME(DATE_EM, '00:02:00') )
```